# "Unable to create a constant value of type .. Only primitive types are supported ..'' in EF query?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a work around for this issue, however I would appreciate it if someone could explain why this is happening and how I would design this for large datasets where my work around would not be viable.

The full error is:
Unable to create a constant value of type 'THPT_Razor.Models.WinType'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

and I am using EF v4.0.

The commented lines are the offending code and the work around is the "For loop"

Thank you in advance.

```
List<WinType> _atype = db.WinTypes.Where(wt => wt.IsWin == false).ToList();
List<WinType> _wtype = db.WinTypes.Where(wt => wt.IsWin == true).ToList();
string test = _wtype.Where(wt => wt.Value ==0).Select(wt => wt.Description).SingleOrDefault();
List<WinCheckDetails> wcd = db.Wins.Include("UserProfiles").Where(w => w.venueLogId == logid).Select(w => new WinCheckDetails
{
    //awarddesc = w.atypeid.HasValue ? _atype.Where( wt=> wt.Value == w.atypeid).Select(wt => wt.Description).SingleOrDefault():string.Empty,
    //windesc = _wtype.Where(wt => wt.Value == w.typeid).Select(wt => wt.Description).Single(),
    atypeid = w.atypeid,
    typeid = w.typeid,
    WinId = w.WinId,
    other = w.other,
    posterid = w.posterid,
    confirmed = w.confirmed,
    posttime = w.posttime,
    game = w.game,
    playerid = w.UserProfile.PlayerID,
    firstname = w.UserProfile.FirstName,
    lastname = w.UserProfile.LastName,
    fullname = w.UserProfile.FirstName + " " + w.UserProfile.LastName
}).OrderBy(o => o.game).ToList();
foreach (WinCheckDetails wc in wcd)
{
    wc.awarddesc = _atype.Where(wt => wt.Value == wc.atypeid).Select(wt => wt.Description).SingleOrDefault();
    wc.windesc = _wtype.Where(wt => wt.Value == wc.typeid).Select(wt => wt.Description).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Consider adding the EF version used, as well as the full error message in the post.

Comment: sorry about that. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_atype` and `_wtype` are lists of `WinType` *in memory* because you are applying `ToList()` to the queries. With respect to database queries they are collections of *constant* values because to perform the query in the database they have to be transmitted to the database server as the values they are in memory. EF doesn't support to transfer such constant values or collections of values from memory to the database *unless* they are values of primitive types (`int` for example). That's the reason why you get an exception.

Did you try to use `_atype` and `_wtype` as `IQueryable` instead of lists:

```
IQueryable<WinType> _atype = db.WinTypes.Where(wt => !wt.IsWin);
IQueryable<WinType> _wtype = db.WinTypes.Where(wt => wt.IsWin);

List<WinCheckDetails> wcd = db.Wins
    .Where(w => w.venueLogId == logid)
    .Select(w => new WinCheckDetails
    {
        awarddesc = w.atypeid.HasValue
            ? _atype.Where(wt=> wt.Value == w.atypeid)
                    .Select(wt => wt.Description).FirstOrDefault()
            : string.Empty,
        windesc = _wtype.Where(wt => wt.Value == w.typeid)
                        .Select(wt => wt.Description).FirstOrDefault(),

        // ... (unchanged)
    }).OrderBy(o => o.game).ToList();
```

I have removed the `Include` because it will be ignored anyway when you perform a projection with `Select`. Also I have replaced `SingleOrDefault` and `Single` by `FirstOrDefault` because both are not supported in a projection (and `First` neither), only `FirstOrDefault` is supported.

I am not sure if that will work. But it should remove your exception (but maybe you'll get another one...).

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you so much for the explanation as well. It makes much more sense than the other explanations that I had found online -- very clear and concise. Like they say knowing is half the battle.